# Setup Creality CR-10 in Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura, creality-cr-10

Can anyone help me find/confirm the information needed to setup the CR-10 in the Cura Software

I have following settings from research:

**Printer Settings**

- x =  300 mm
- y =  300 mm
- z =  400 mm
- Build Plate = Rectangular
- Machine Center is Zero = Checked
- Heated Bed = Checked
- G-code Flavor = RepRap (Marlin/Sprinter) **-- Uncertain - please help confirm this**

**Print Head Settings**

- X min = **Unclear where this comes from**
- Y min = **Unclear where this comes from**
- X max = **Unclear where this comes from**
- Y max = **Unclear where this comes from**
- Gantry Height = **Unclear where this is measured from**
- Number of Extruders = 1
- Material Diameter - 1.75 mm
- Nozzle size = 0.4 mm

Comment: **Adding on the answer by @tjb1 to confirm** The GCode Flavor is indeed RepRap.

Comment: Have you found and fixed the problem? If so, have the answers below led you to the solution? Please vote to accept an answer (using the green tick button next to the question) so this question is not bumped up once in a while and can be removed from the unanswered question list. You may even add your own solution and accept that after 48 hours! If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question.

Answer (score 5):

**GCode flavor**: the firmware your machine uses. Google tells me CR-10 uses Marlin, so you should select that. Volumetric Marlin is not very common.

Print Head Settings
**X/Y min/max** define the bounding box of the area your print head takes up. Measure the distance from the centre of the nozzle to the left-most point of the print head and do the same for the right-most, front-most and back-most.

**Gantry Height** is the distance from the tip of the nozzle to the lowest point of the gantry, which is the axle on which the print head is mounted.

These print head settings are only used for one-at-a-time printing.

Comment: This is actually the [possibly] correct answer.  The CR-10 has a single extruder, so all measurements for the X/Y min/max should actually all be from the _centre_ of the nozzle, not one of its sides (the formulation "left nozzle" in the answer is confusing, IMO).

Comment: Yes, the measurements should be from the center of the nozzle. In case there are multiple nozzles all measurements are by convention done w.r.t. the first nozzle, which is generally chosen to be the left-most one if they are sitting beside eachother.


Actually you can do all measurements w.r.t. another point, but then you'd have to update your nozzle offsets as well, which is only possible in the custom FDM printer wizard if you select more than 1 extruder.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [this answer](/a/4438), the "Machine Center is Zero", should **not** be checked. It will begin the print in the current location of the Printing Head.

Comment: Totally true, and well spotted (missed by the other answers).